# Convert flat structure to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my attempts to make a generic CRUD system for Mongo DB and Mongoose I've ran into this challenge. When the user updates a record and I read the req.body the fields are returned in a flat structure. But some of my models have nested records, hence the dot notation.

I need to unwrap below into an object so I can pass it to Mongo DB.

I have:

```
var data = {
    'details.location.unit': undefined,
    'details.location.floor': undefined,
    'details.location.streetNumber': '67',
    'details.location.streetName': 'Brown St',
    'details.location.suburb': 'potts point',
    'details.location.postcode': 2011,
    'details.location.city': 'sydney',
    'details.location.state': 'nsw',
    'details.location.country': 'australia',
    'details.contact.phone': [ '(02) 2376 5678', '(02) 1234 5678' ],
    'details.contact.url': 'http://www.example.com',
    'details.contact.email': 'me@example.com'
}
```

And want to turn it into:

```
var data = {
    details:{
        location: {
            unit': undefined,
            floor': undefined,
            streetNumber': '67',
            streetName': 'Brown St',
            suburb': 'potts point'
        },

        contact: {
          phone': [ '(02) 2376 5678', '(02) 1234 5678' ],
          url: 'http://www.example.com',
          email: 'me@example.com',  
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the array in there as well. That needs to be JSON parsed. Not quite sure how to attack this one!

For another part of the project I used this function to access an object by string accessors. Perhaps it can be repurposed?

```
// @param {object} data
// @param {string} accessor e.g 'vehicles.cars.toyota'
// @return {*}
var getValueByAccessor = function (data, accessor) {

    var keys = accessor.split('.'),
        result = data;

    while (keys.length > 0) {
        var key = keys.shift();

        if (typeof result[key] !== 'undefined') {
            result = result[key];
        }

        else {
            result = null;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you just experiencing or have a good reason not to use an existing MongoDB tool/library/CMS that comes with CRUD support? Hint: when posting an HTML form, you can receive an associative array on the server by using square brackets in the field names. E.g. `<input type ="text" name="details[location][unit]" value="" />` and `<input type ="text" name="details[location][floor]" value="" />` will result in `req.body.details` being `{location: {unit: "", floor: ""}}`

Comment: Why do you send the data in a format you don't want? If you control the client side, you can just send the json in the form you want it to be in the server.

Comment: I have to second the *"just send it that way"* sentiment. You already have an "array" in there anyway. If you can send that data then you can serialize the rest of the structure as JSON and just deserialize on receipt.

Comment: Marekful, I couldn't find a suitable Mongo CRUD tool with a GUI as an npm module that I could easily integrate on my website. The ones I looked at were more like abstraction layers like Mongoose. So I decided to smash my own one together with Node and Bootstrap. But if you say they are out there I probably haven't looked hard enough.  Can you point me to a few good ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
    'details.location.unit': undefined,
    'details.location.floor': undefined,
    'details.location.streetNumber': '67',
    'details.location.streetName': 'Brown St',
    'details.location.suburb': 'potts point',
    'details.location.postcode': 2011,
    'details.location.city': 'sydney',
    'details.location.state': 'nsw',
    'details.location.country': 'australia',
    'details.contact.phone': [ '(02) 2376 5678', '(02) 1234 5678' ],
    'details.contact.url': 'http://www.example.com',
    'details.contact.email': 'me@example.com'
}

var setNewValue = function (obj, chain, value) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < chain.length - 1) {
        obj[chain[i]]=obj[chain[i]] || {};
        obj = obj[chain[i]];
        i++;
    }
    obj[chain[i]] = value;
};

var convertedObject={};
for(var a in data)if(data.hasOwnProperty(a)){
    var pathArr=a.split('.');
    var value=data[a];
    setNewValue (convertedObject, pathArr, value);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!